# Retry after timeout in Jenkins pipeline - workarounds

Tags: jenkins, timeout, jenkins-pipeline

It's a known Jenkins issue that [pipeline retry operation doesn't retry when there is a timeout inside of it](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51454).

Surely there are some workarounds to force `retry` (or substitute) to work after a timeout occurs?

Sample code where `retry` is not triggered:

```
retry(3) {
  timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') {
    // Something that can fail
  }
}
```

Unless caught, the timeout error (`org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException`) causes the entire job to abort.

Comment: are you writing scripted pipeline or declarative?

Comment: Technically declarative, but with `script` clauses inserted at every stage, so in fact both can be used. The purpose of this `script { retry { timeout` is to interrupt after a few minutes the `docker push` stage, which sometimes hangs for hours.

Comment: id look into why it hangs for hours rather than workaround it. Creating techdept is not fun :)

Comment: I did, but it seems to be related to lack of timeout in docker itself, which is outside of my control, see e.g. [others having the same problem](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-push-to-docker-io-hub-hangs-as-waiting-with-no-error-or-timeout/9073) with docker.

Comment: You could create a function that goes around your docker push and us an internal counter to count to 5 minutes and if docker has not exited properly try again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[JENKINS-51454](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-51454) has been fixed in [jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin#144](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/pull/144) and released in [2.24](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/releases/tag/workflow-basic-steps-2.24) ([Changelog](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/blob/fcd86dc54c549e1bcc48d13d4ee2ca7e66006253/CHANGELOG.md)).

Comment: Thanks a lot @basil-crow, it was long time coming:)

Answer (score 11):

A good workaround, as suggested by [Basil Crow](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=basil) [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51454) is to insert `try - catch` *between* `retry` and `timeout` to consume the timeout error (`FlowInterruptedException`) without passing it to `retry`. As soon as we replace `FlowInterruptedException` with a custom error, `retry` kicks in and starts cooperating correctly even with `timeout` inside.

Example:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException

retry(3) {

  try {

      timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') {

        // something that can fail

      } // timeout ends

  } catch (FlowInterruptedException e) {
      // we re-throw as a different error, that would not 
      // cause retry() to fail (workaround for issue JENKINS-51454)
      error 'Timeout!'

  } // try ends

} // retry ends
```

Comment: but you should know: if the user stops the execution while you are waiting for the timeout that will also create a `FlowInterruptedException`...